# How can I get an image or link to show up in an Oracle APEX CLASSIC Report?

Tags: html, report, oracle-apex

I want to do something like this:

```
select 
a,
'<img src="/i/image.png" width="24px"/>' b
from myTable;
```

but html is showing like text.

How to solve this?

Comment: please provide more info how your html look like ?

Comment: Html looks like : <img src="/i/image.png" width="24px"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the column attributes and set the Display As property to "Standard Report Column" and then the HTML will not be escaped.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i dont understand where is it? Are you sure that are you talking about Classic report? In my Column Attributes in my report looks like this - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27452391/Untitled.png

Comment: I can't view dropbox from my place of work.  But what version of APEX are you on?  My answer is correct for Classic Reports in APEX 4.0 up, I can't remember what earlier versions had.

Comment: I have Application Express 4.1.1. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/99639265.png/

Comment: You have to click on the edit (pencil) icon next to the column in the Report Attributes tab to bring up the Column Attributes page where this property can be set.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find the 'Display As' column property in more recent APEX-version. What ended up working with me was setting the 'Escape special characters' to NO in the Security section of the column attributes. [Column attributes > Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZryH.png)